# What does TS Eliot mean by "old dispensation" in The Journey of the Magi?

Tags: history, christmas, language

In T. S. Eliot's poem *[The Journey of the Magi](http://www.ishk.org/school/poem/poem_013.html)* he's offering a imaginative view into the interior experience of one of the wise men from the East who came to Jesus's birthplace.

The last few lines of that poem are:

> We had evidence and no doubt. I had seen birth and death,
>       But had thought they were different; this Birth was
>       Hard and bitter agony for us, like Death, our death.
>       We returned to our places, these Kingdoms,
>       But no longer at ease here, in the old dispensation,
>       With an alien people clutching their gods.
>       I should be glad of another death.

What does he mean by *old dispensation* here?  Does this come from the Bible (I can't find it there)?  Does it come from church history?

Comment: "He" is a she: Mary Ann Evans; George Eliot: a nom de plume.

Comment: Alack alas, you lack a lass the poet is not she.

Comment: TS Eliot != George Eliot; and even if it were, this still wouldn't answer the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He means the same thing as "[the old covenant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_covenant)" (Judaism), but stated in the language of [dispensationalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispensationalism), which classifies the [different timeline "slices"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispensationalist_theology) of God's plan. We tend to think of it as old covenant/new covenant but if you start getting really anal about it and analyzing "what about before Moses" and "what about after the Rapture" you get a bit more of a complicated set of salvation schemes over time, or "dispensations."

Edit: I guess I'm surprised that this is a contentious or misunderstood point, has no one heard of dispensationalism? I provided the links above for a reason. **[Mastery and escape: T.S. Eliot and the dialectic of modernism](http://books.google.com/books?id=7yYyY_2KufYC&lpg=PA7&ots=uAVU2Nm4xN&dq=t.s.%20eliot%20dispensationalism&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q=dispensationalism&f=false)** discusses Eliot's dispensationalism specifically and how he uses this term in much of his writing. He was, you know, into it.

Comment: I thought the Magi were pagans?

Comment: The poem wasn't written by the magi, but an old Pseudo-British white guy, FYI.

Comment: Right. But if it's about pagans encountering Christ, I don't see how the "old dispensation" can refer to Judaism.

Comment: 1.it's a poem not a documentary, maybe they learned the term wherever they learned English. </sarcasm>

Comment: 2. The Magi may have been Jewish maybe not, but if not they certainly have lots of knowledge of Judaism and the Prophets. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_Magi

Comment: I'm just thinking about the poem here. I don't think the poem makes any sense if the speaker of the poem is understood as being Jewish.

Comment: @BenDunlap: Agreed. The plural "gods" on the following line makes Judaism seem especially unlikely.